# Get parent page id which is already a child - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the parent ID of a page. I've searched around but the only things I can find on this get the top level parent ID.

I have 3 layers of pages:

```
-page 1  
-------page 2  
-------------page 3
```

**page 3 is a child of page 2, page 2 is a child of page 1.**

If I'm currently on the page 3 page how can I get the ID of the page directly above it? (page 2)

Appreciate any help!

Comment: try posting over here on the wordpress SE site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

With in the global $post you can simply do is use 
`$post->post_parent`

Comment: Moeed did you get your answer?